# Get the selected index from WKPickerInterface

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2

I can get the `WKInterfacePicker` to call `pickerDidSettle`, but how can I get the index of the selected item?

```
@IBAction override func pickerDidSettle(picker: WKInterfacePicker) {
    print("Picker settled to index: \(picker)")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> Each time the picker value changes, the WKInterfacePicker object
>   reports the change to its associated action method. The format of this
>   action method is as follows:
>
> **OBJECTIVE-C**
>
> -(IBAction)pickerAction:(NSInteger)index
>
> **SWIFT**
>    @IBAction func pickerAction(index: Int)
>
> You can use the action method’s index value to obtain the selected
>   item from the array of items you used to configure the picker. The
>   picker reports every change to its action method, regardless of how
>   fast the user turns the Digital Crown. If your app should respond only
>   to the item that the user selected, use the pickerDidSettle: method of
>   WKInterfaceController to get the selected item instead.

[Source Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfacePicker_class/)

[UPDATED SOURCE LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Picker.html)

Comment: The quoted text is no longer at the source link. Try this link: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Picker.html)

Comment: However, it does not explain how to get the selected item from a Picker.

Comment: Thanks for the updated link. And its mention in the quoted text that you can use "action method’s index value to obtain the selected item from the array of items " as picker reports every change to its method.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this

Create in .h file

```
NSInteger PickerIndex;
```

swift

```
 var PickerIndex: Int
```

Then in my .m

```
 - (IBAction)pickerAction:(NSInteger)index {

       PickerIndex = index;
}
```

swift

```
@IBAction func pickerAction(index: Int) {

 PickerIndex = index

}
```

* Don't forget to link the IBAction in Interface Builder

And then use it in pickerDidSettle method

```
-(void)pickerDidSettle:(WKInterfacePicker *)picker{

   NSLog(@"Selected Index: %ld",(long)PickerIndex);

}
```

swift

```
func pickerDidSettle(_ picker: WKInterfacePicker) {

     print(PickerIndex)

}
```